# how to get a levelTraversal order list for a tree?

Tags: java

I know how to get preorder and postorder and inorder, but when I use similar method to get levelTraversal it meets problem, it will add all node for right and left each.
levelTraversal: same level, get right to left for each level.

```
public List<Node> postorder() {
List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
postOrderHelper(this.root, list);
return list;
}


private void postOrderHelper(Node node, List<Node> list) {
    if (node != null && node.key != null) {
    postOrderHelper(node.left, list);
    postOrderHelper(node.right, list);
    list.add(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a fundamentally different concept. You are not handling one node at a time but a list of nodes which are at the same level.